# Not able to fulfill "Guideline 3.2 - Business" while releasing app on App Store

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

I am working on the app for my client who has no registration screen and app is private for specific people only, registration only happening from backend by the administrator. When I tried to release it on "App Store" they given me following reason of rejection.

> Hello,
>
> The issues we previously identified still need your attention.
>
> If you have any questions, we are here to help. Reply to this message
> in App Store Connect and let us know.
>
> Guideline 3.2 - Business
>
> We found in our review that your app is intended to be used by a
> specific business or organization, including partners, clients, or
> employees, but you've selected public distribution on the App Store in
> App Store Connect. Since the App Store is intended for apps with a
> public audience, we recommend reviewing the other distribution options
> available to you through your Apple Developer Program Account.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, review the other distribution options available
> for apps designed for specific businesses or organizations and choose
> a distribution option that works for your app and users. You can
> review these app distribution options on Apple Developer.
>
> Resources
>
> - Learn more about custom app distribution using Apple Business Manager or Apple School Manager.
> - Learn more about unlisted app distribution.

And Here is my reply to support team:

> Hi Apple Support,
>
> Thank you for your app review. This is to explain our business use case and we are looking for your expert advice on how we can proceed with the app store release.
>
> We are in the agriculture business, and we are providing innovative hardware, cloud platforms, and mobile apps for our customers. Our customers are limited and fixed meaning no unknown or no one from public members gonna be registered on the forum. We as backend admins will create accounts for our customers and provide the credentials to them and then customers will use the web portal and mobile app without registration. As per our privacy policy, we cannot allow someone to self-register with our platform because our geo graphical data is private. So no registration process exists on our platform. All the user activities are monitored and controlled by system admins.
>
> Please advise us on other subsequent ways to proceed with the release.

I am looking for way or steps, how and which cateogry can I release my app.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It sounds like a good candidate for [unlisted app distribution](https://developer.apple.com/support/unlisted-app-distribution/)

Comment: @Paulw11 I Already selected this option in App Distribution Method :
Private — Available as a custom app on Apple Business Manager or Apple School Manager still I am missing something? and I don't know what

Comment: No, you probably don't want a custom app. That only lets you distribute to organisations with Apple Business Manager. Unlisted app distribution lets anyone with the link install it, but it isn't discoverable on the App Store. Follow the instructions on the page I linked to. Submit for app review and note that it will be an unlisted app in the review notes. Then submit the unlisted app application.

Comment: @Paulw11 My app has no functionality for registration at all to make my app unlisted I have to release my app and then be able to make my app unlisted right so for that I am not even able to release it once. (so can you plz guide me on what I am missing)

Comment: Your app doesn't need a registration function. Follow the steps outlined on the page that I linked to and that I explained. Submit your app for review with a note that it will be an unlisted app and then immediately submit a request for unlisted distribution. You cannot release and then convert to unlisted. Once your app is approved you will be given an unlisted distribution url.

Comment: @Paulw11 so when i submit my app for app review and say that I will make this app unlisted then that approves my app then I apply for unlisted app?

Comment: No.  Submit your app for review with a note that it will be unlisted.  Then, while it is still "pending review" fill in the unlisted app request.

Comment: On filling "Have you submitted your app to the App Store for review?" 
I fill "no" as we have to then they show me this validation "Before you request unlisted app distribution, your app must be ready for final distribution and submitted to App Review."

Comment: You must fill "yes" because I have told you several times your app must be in "waiting for review"state. "ready for final distribution and submitted to App Review." means that your app is finished (ie not beta, not still being developed - it is "ready for final distribution".  This does not mean it has been reviewed) and has been *submitted* for app review.

Answer (score -1):

if less than 100 people, ad-hoc release is good.
more than that like less than 1k and target to release at company internal, enterprise develop and distribution makes more sense, with a x server.

just 2 cents, apple's guideline is if you do not want to share to all public, then probably appstore is not the place.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).